# Can't access nautilus in xrdp client

Tags: nautilus

When I am on my pc connected to server, I can't open nautilus. When I execute sudo nautilus it types `authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified`

Answer (score -1):

You do not specify which version of Ubuntu you are running....

So, If your are running Ubuntu 22.04 or 23.10, you can try to run the following command in your remote session

```
xhost si:localuser:root 
sudo nautilus
```

This should allow you to start nautilus file explorer.....

Till next time
See ya